# How do I extract a series of n rows after initial row extraction?

Tags: r

Suppose I have matrix called M,

```
"Date" "X" "Y"
1991    T   10
1992    T   5
1993    F   2
1994    F   1
1995    T   7
```

where date is a character value, X is Boolean, and Y is numeric. Also, assume that the total number of rows are 50, each filled with values mentioned above.

My initial selection criteria is for the second column to be True. Thus,

```
initial_row<-M[M[,2]==T,]
```

I am looking for a way to extract 10 rows (or any constant number) following the initial row, regardless of their values on any column. Basically, I'm trying to mine all the rows that follow the initial extraction, then move on until next row that meets the initial selection criteria.

Comment: @coffieinjunky Hi, I just posted a new question. Could you help me out?

Comment: He won't get that notification unless he's visited this post recently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should extract the rows following the initial rows and put the batches of rows into a list

```
const <- 10
lapply(which(M$X), function(n){
  indices <- n + 1:const # 0:const to include initial row
  indices <- indices[indices <= nrow(M)] # exclude out of bounds values
  M[indices,]
})
```

Comment: It says 'Error in which(Bullish) : argument to 'which' is not logical'.

Comment: I tried it with removing the which(), and now it says Error in n + 0:const : non-numeric argument to binary operator.

Comment: Ok, now it's saying $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors. @Richard Telford.

Comment: is M really a matrix? A matrix must have all columns of the same type, so you cannot have one character, one logical and one numeric column. All would be promoted to character. You should have your data in a data.frame, which allow columns to be of different types. Then M$X will work

Comment: Nevermind I got it to work. Thank you very much, Professor.